# Pseudo classes for paragraph in css aren't working

Tags: html, css

This is the question:

I am working on a assignment at codecademy.com, which goes like this:

On the CSS tab:

- Set the second paragraph to the font-family Tahoma.
- Set the third paragraph to have the color #CC0000.
- Set the fourth paragraph to have the background-color #00FF00.
- Set the fifth paragraph to have the font-size 22px.

This is my html code :

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>I'm the first child!</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>           
    </div>
</body>
```

and this is my css code:

```
p:first-child {
    font-family: cursive;
}

p:second-child {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

p:third-child {
    color: #CC0000;
}

p:fourth-child {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}

p:fifth-child {
    font-size: 22px
}
```

Why does only the first pseudo class work on the first paragraph, but not the other pseudo classes  on the other paragraphs?

Please feel free to help me with this problem i face now.

Thanks, and greetings from the Netherlands!

Comment: `second-child` and all the later pseudo-selectors, don't exist. `first-child`, `last-child`, and things like `nth-child` do.

Comment: You may find [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) more helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

This css pseudo classes doesn't exists. The only one that exist is first child.

[Pseudo-Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes):

- [`:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)
- [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)
- [`:default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:default)
- [`:dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir)
- [`:disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled)
- [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)
- [`:enabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:enabled)
- [`:first`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first)
- [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)
- [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)
- [`:fullscreen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen)
- [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)
- [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)
- [`:indeterminate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate)
- [`:in-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:in-range)
- [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)
- [`:lang()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang)
- [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)
- [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type)
- [`:left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:left)
- [`:link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link)
- [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
- [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)
- [`:nth-last-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type)
- [`:nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)
- [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child)
- [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type)
- [`:optional`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:optional)
- [`:out-of-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:out-of-range)
- [`:read-only`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-only)
- [`:read-write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-write)
- [`:required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required)
- [`:right`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:right)
- [`:root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:root)
- [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope)
- [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)
- [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid)
- [`:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

The correct one for your example is to use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

```
p:first-child {
    font-family: cursive;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
    color: #CC0000;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
    font-size: 22px
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xy7odaq/)

Comment: +1 great answer, maybe you could add how he uses `:nth-child`

Comment: The links are broken.

Comment: @Goosebumbs doesn't it beat the point of the OP doing a course on CSS if someone answers the question for them?

Answer (score 1):

It's because only the `:first-child` in your code does exist and you should use CSS `:nth-child(n)` selectors to select other elements:

The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9qbpn2j/)**

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>I'm the first child!</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
        <p>We're not.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
p:first-child {
    font-family: cursive;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
    font-family: Tahoma;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
    color: #CC0000;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
    font-size: 22px
}
```